# Uploading a file with AJAX to a .NET 5 MVC controller works only sometimes

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, form-data

This is such a mystery that I have no idea how to troubleshoot any further.

Basically, I have a form in HTML 5 and I send the contents of an input="file" element to an action in my .NET 5 MVC controller. I only tried to run this on my local machine in VS 2022. This is the outcome in the controller when the file goes through:

[image: success]

So I know the Jquery AJAX function works. I send the file via Formdata with processData: false and all that jazz. It should be solid. However when I run it again with the same image:

[image]

I am using a 1 kb big file, so there is no room for error regarding file size. If I click the little "thread" button it says that the evaluation of the function timed out. If I click continue to the next breakpoint the program will never get to the next breakpoint. It just keeps running, but never reaching another line.

How do I even troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does formData have data. Is the value it passes into the server null.

Comment: Just before the AJAX call, when I display formData in JS, it shows the object. The JS output is the same when the formData goes through as well as when it does not, so I gather the object is not missing when it fails.